# Datasheet hunting -

Tags: voltage, fpga, datasheet, xilinx, io

I'm having difficulty trying to figure out voltage outputs for FPGAs. Let's use the [Xilinx XC3S2000 FG900](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds099.pdf) as an example, and say I'm trying to figure out the voltage for pin T22. I do a search for the pin which tells me it's I/O and located on bank 3 (table 107), but no voltage information is present. I check the I/O capabilities (table 2) which lists several different types, but I'm unsure which type bank 3 I/O is (or should I be using table 8? or 10?). What step am I missing?

Very basic question, but it's easy to get lost in FPGA documentation. Any help is greatly appreciated- thanks!

Comment: I think what you want is on page 121 "VCCO Type: Output Voltage Supply for I/O Bank".

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, each 'Bank' usually has either its own Vccio pin, or shares one with other banks. Whatever voltage you apply to this pin is the I/O voltage that will be used for all pins on that bank. So say you connect Vccio=2.5V, then you can use a 2.5V I/O standard. Table 10 on page 17 of that datasheet lists the required Vccio voltage for different I/O standards of that device.

Now some more complex FPGAs can support multiple input I/O standards for one Vccio voltage - so some you can set Vccio=2.5, but then it is compatible with 1.8V, 2.5V or 3.3V inputs. Though the output is usually limited to whatever voltage you use.

Furthermore, in the development tools, there is usually a pin planner type tool that allows you to specify what voltage standard you would like each pin to be, it can then analyse that during fitting to see if say all the pins on the same bank can work with the same Vccio voltage - you can't have a 1.8V LVCMOS output on a 2.5V bank for example.
They can then also give you a report to tell you what voltages are required on what I/O banks to support your design.

Answer (score 1):

The I/O blocks of FPGAs are usually configurable for different interface standards, so the precise voltage/current specifications for particular pin depend on which standard you've configured the pin for, as well as what voltage you're suppling to the I/O bank in which that pin resides. That's why the datasheet is so complicated. The development tools will often give you that information for your specific design anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Check the .PAD file that comes out of the place and route process - that tells you what IOSTANDARD is used on each pin.  Only then you can look that up in the docs.